# Salesforce Visual Flow Help: Too Many SOQL Queries 101

Tags: process-builder, error, visual-workflow

I have a visual flow that is kicked off by a process builder process. This flow is doing a record lookup on an object to find a match and then updating a record. When I import records to said object I got the infamous error "Too Many SOQL queries: 101" I understand that in order to resolve this issue I would need to 'bulkify' this process in some sense but I can't think of any way to do that with this process and flow. Am I just screwed or is there something I am missing?

[image: Flow]

Thanks,

Comment: Check this link about bulkifying flow http://succeedwithsalesforce.com/5-best-practices-that-must-be-followed-when-building-flows/

Comment: Thanks. I will review and see what I can do here to make this process run better. My concern though is if I want to kick this process of for a couple thousand records. That seems to be when the issue is arising.

Comment: Even if you bulkify process/workflow, from my experience, periodically you'll run into  this issue performing mass updates. Is it not possible to modify records externally and then update in SF (e.g. from Excel)?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that for the initial load of the records, and I think that is just going to be what I will have to go with.